# How to avoid limit SOQL When tried to update duplicate value

Tags: apex, limits

i have a code to check duplicate value, and it will update only one data and remove the others with the same mobilephone and account.

example, i have 100 data, with 50 data (Account A and Mobile A) and 50 data (Account B and Mobile B). it'll delete 98 data and update 1 data account and mobile A, and update 1 data account and mobile B

this is what i have done, but i got error soql 101. do you have any idea how to update my code to be clean?? really need ur help guys, thanks

```
Set<ID> idValContact = new Set<ID>();
List<Contact> lstcontobeupdate = new List<Contact>();
List<ContactWrap> lsttobeupdate2 = new List<ContactWrap>();    
for(Contact c : lstCont){
    if(c.MobilePhone != NULL && c.LastName != NULL){
        //case 1 = Kalo semisal verify, aktif dan source SPS
        List<Contact> case1 = [SELECT ID, Name FROM Contact WHERE Source__c = 'SPS' AND Verified__c = TRUE AND Is_Active__c = TRUE
                               AND AccountId =: c.AccountId AND MobilePhone =:c.MobilePhone ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1];    //activation date
        if(case1.size() > 0){
           idValContact.add(case1[0].Id);
        }
        else{
            //case 2 = kalo semisal verify, aktif dan source selain SPS
            List<Contact> case2 = [SELECT ID, Name FROM Contact WHERE Source__c != 'SPS' AND Verified__c = TRUE AND Is_Active__c = TRUE 
                                   AND AccountId =:c.AccountId AND MobilePhone =:c.MobilePhone ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1 ];    //date approved
            if(case2.size()>0){
              idValContact.add(case2[0].Id);
            }
            else{
                //case 3 = kalo semisal not verify, not active dan source SPS
                List<Contact> case3 = [SELECT ID, Name FROM Contact WHERE Source__c = 'SPS' AND (Verified__c = FALSE OR Is_Active__c = FALSE) 
                                       AND AccountId =: c.AccountId AND MobilePhone =:c.MobilePhone ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
                if(case3.size()>0){
                  idValContact.add(case3[0].Id);
                }
                else{
                    //case 4 = kalo semisal not verify, not active dan source selain SPS
                    List<Contact> case4 = [SELECT ID, Name FROM Contact WHERE Source__c != 'SPS' AND (Verified__c = FALSE OR Is_Active__c = FALSE) 
                                           AND AccountId =: c.AccountId AND MobilePhone =:c.MobilePhone ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1 ];
                    if(case4.size()>0){
                       idValContact.add(case4[0].Id);
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
if(idValContact.size() > 0){
    lstcontobeupdate = [SELECT ID FROM Contact Where ID IN :idValContact];            
    for(Integer i = (lstCont.size()-1) ; i>= 0 ; i--){
        String s = lstCont[i].ID;
        for(Integer j = (lstcontobeupdate.size()-1) ; j>= 0 ; j--){
            String sjw = lstcontobeupdate[j].ID;
            if(s.contains(sjw)){
                lstCont.remove(i);
            }
        }
    } 
    List<Contact> lstcondeleted = new List<Contact>();              //update invalid contact
    List<Contact> lstconupdated = new List<Contact>();              //update valid contact to be actived and verified
    //lst Contact setelah yang valid di remove
    for(Contact c : lstCont){
        //delete contact duplicate
    }
    for(Contact c: lstconupdated){  
        //update yg dipertahanin
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is against best practices to put any SOQL in a loop. There are limited exceptions to this, but this isn't one of them. Instead, you're going to want to query all the necessary records, then perform matching, and finally, perform your updates. Your code is kind of hard to read, so I'm making some assumptions here. Hopefully, however, this will get you started.

```
// Filters to use
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<String> mobilePhones = new Set<String>();

// Keep track of current "winners"
Map<Contact, Contact> contactMap = new Map<Contact, Contact>();
// And keep track of current "losers"
List<Contact> contactsToDelete = new List<Contact>();

// We will use these as key-value pairs
for(Contact c: lstCont) {
    mobilePhones.add(c.mobilePhone);
    accountIds.add(c.accountId);
}

// Ignore null values
mobilePhones.remove(null);
accountIds.remove(null);

for(Contact c: [SELECT AccountId, MobileNumber, Source__c, Verified__c, Is_Active__c 
                FROM Contact 
                WHERE AccountId = :accountIds AND MobilePhone = :mobilePhone 
                ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC]) {
    // Create a lookup key
    Contact key = new Contact(
        AccountId=c.AccountId, 
        MobilePhone=c.MobilePhone
    );
    // Grab the current winner, if any
    Contact temp = contactMap.get(key);
    
    if(temp == null || // No winner yet.
        (temp.Source__c != 'SPS' && c.Source__c == 'SPS') || // Incoming record has better source
        ((!temp.Verified__c || !temp.Is_Active__c) && (c.Verified__c && c.Is_Active__c)) // Incoming record has better verified/active
    ) {
        // Update the winner
        temp = contactMap.put(key, temp);
        // The previous winner is now the loser
        if(temp != null) {
            contactsToDelete.add(temp);
        }
    } else {
        // This contact already lost
        contactsToDelete.add(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: hy thankyou for the answer, but i kinda confuses about 

if(temp == null || (temp.Source__c != 'SPS' && c.Source__c == 'SPS') ||        ((!temp.Verified__c || !temp.Is_Active__c) && (c.Verified__c && c.Is_Active__c))
)

how can i know which one is the winner? like my Case <List>?

Comment: @MustikaFarma We prefer the records from newest to oldest, and for each record, we check if that mobile number/account number matches and either (a) there's no value yet, (b) the previous source was not SPS but the new one is, or (c) the old one wasn't verified/active and the new one is. That's the same effect as you had in your code, but using just one query instead of four per record.

Comment: oh i see, but why the value of  Contact temp = contactMap.get(key); is always null?
evntho key already have data?

Comment: @MustikaFarma It shouldn't always be null, if there is a bulk amount of records you're examining. We just want to check if contactMap.get(key) is null first to avoid a later null pointer exception.

Comment: but, it always set null in temp = contactMap.put(key, temp); event its in condition,
is it because the value of temp is null? thankyou for the answer, it help me alot :))

this is my log: https://im.ge/i/1oOsMG
code: https://im.ge/i/1oO59F